# Attributed string underline not working with external fonts

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have `UITextView` and  want to add links part of the text in it.These embedded links should be underlined.When I set its `font` as one of the built-in's it works properly but with `Ubuntu font` it does not work even though hyperlinks color is set.

```
let linkTextView = UITextView()
let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Design.colorPrimary,
        NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,]
linkTextView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
linkTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

let allText = "example link"
let linkText = "link"
let NStext = NSString(string: allText)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: allText)

attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: NSURL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!, range: NStext.range(of: linkText))
linkTextView.attributedText = attributedString
linkTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

linkTextView.font = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 20)!//this does not
//linkTextView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)! // this works
```

ArialMT:

[image]

Ubuntu:

[image]

so how can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83580/ubuntu-font-family-and-mac-os-x-confusing-font-name-and-font).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the font before setting the attributed string?

The underline could be removed when you change the font when the textColor isn't affected by the font.

Regards

Comment: When I try to change font before setting attributed string it ignores font that I have set, underlines hyperlinks with default font

Comment: And interestingly `NSUnderlineStyle.double` works properly with both `Ubuntu` and `ArialMT`

Comment: And did you try setting the font in the attributes with NSFontAttributeName?

Comment: I am not sure that `NSFontAttributeName` can be used in swift 4.2. It deprecated to NSAttributedString.font as far as I know and compiler does not suggesting it.